# WooCommerce - calculate shipping per line item when quantity is split

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am splitting up cart quantities in to blocks of 6, ie. if a customer adds 8 into the cart, it is added to the cart as 2 rows, the first with 6 and the second with 2 as the quantity.

The reason for this is that we are using table rate shipping plugin to calculate the shipping up to 6 (the product can only be shipped a maximum of 6 at a time so any more than that is a separate shipment), essentially, the shipping needs to be calculated per line in blocks of 6. I have set the table rate shipping to calculate per line item but it still seems to be calculating it all as a single product and in this case because the overall quantity is over 6, it simply says no shipping methods available. Am I missing something?

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

The code I am using to split the cart is as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'split_multiple_quantity_products_to_separate_cart_items', 10, 6 );
function split_multiple_quantity_products_to_separate_cart_items( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {

    $groupNumber = 6;

    // If product has more than 1 quantity
    if ( $quantity > $groupNumber ) {

        // Get whole number for quantity/max
        $quantityWhole = floor($quantity / $groupNumber);

        $quantityRemaining = $quantity - ($quantityWhole * $groupNumber);


        // Keep the product but set its quantity to 6
        WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $groupNumber );

        // Run a loop 1 less than the total quantity
        for ( $i = 1; $i <= $quantityWhole -1; $i++ ) {
             // * Set a unique key.
             // * This is what actually forces the product into its own cart line item
            $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() . "Hey" );

            // Add the product as a new line item with the same variations that were passed
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $groupNumber, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
        }

        if($quantityRemaining) {
            // * Set a unique key.
             // * This is what actually forces the product into its own cart line item
            $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() . "Hey" );

            // Add the product as a new line item with the same variations that were passed
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantityRemaining, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
        }

        WC()->cart->calculate_shipping( );


    }

}
```

I will attach 2 screenshots, the first is the shipping as calculated for just 6 items and then when this is split to 2 lines for higher quantities it doesn't calculate the shipping for each line, despite being set to do so.

[image]

[image]